# Laravel Eloquent HasManyThrough returning empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble getting a query from HasManyThrough relation in Eloquent.

These are my tables

**PAGES**

- id
- *columns*
- slideshow_fk

**SLIDESHOWS**

- id
- *columns*

**SLIDES**

- id
- *columns*
- slideshow_id

My Page model:

```
class Page extends Model
{
    public function slideshow_id(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Slideshow::class);
    }
    public function slides(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Slide','App\Slideshow','id','slideshow_id','slideshow_fk');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$page=Page::where("slug","=",$slug)->with('slides')->first();
```

**Query log:** I am not Page ID:3 with slideshow_fk:1, [? = 1]

```
select `slides`.*, `slideshows`.`id` from `slides` inner join `slideshows` on `slideshows`.`id` = `slides`.`slideshow_id` where `slideshows`.`id` in (?)
```

**page->slides array:**

```
[]
```

**PhpMyAdmin SQL copy/paste:**

http://prntscr.com/e0hy4e

Which are the correct 3 slides I need for my page.

Why do I get an **empty array**?

Comment: have you checked    Page::where("slug","=",$slug)->first(); is returning something ?

Comment: Yes, I get the page returned: {"id":3,"name":"xxx","description":"xxx.","slug":"koledar","slideshow_fk":1,"created_at":"2017-01-24 12:05:23","updated_at":"2017-01-24 12:05:23","slides":[]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot you [hasManyThrough()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) here as your implementation doesn't support the need for one.

Say you have three models `A`, `B` and `C` and `A` want to connect to `C` via `B`.

Then if you want to use `hasManyThrough()`

- `B` needs to have `A`'s `primary key` as a `foreign key`
- `C` needs to have `B`'s `primary key` as a `foreign key`

That is `A <- B <- C`

If I put this to your example, what you have is

- `A` have `B`'s `primary key` as a `foreign key`
- `C` have `B`'s `primary key` as a `foreign key`

Which is `A -> B <- C`.

What you can do here is define models like this.

```
class Pages extends Model
{
    public function slideshow()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Slideshow::class);
    }
}

class Slideshow extends Model
{
    public function slides()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Slides::class);
    }

}

class Slides extends Model
{

}
```

And query like

```
$pags = Pages::with('slideshow.slides')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
```

I suggest using proper naming conventions.

Comment: This makes total sense! Thanks, I will try in next few minutes

Comment: Okay I got it to work, **thank you** so much! I defined my Page model relations like this: _return $this->hasOne('App\Slideshow','id','slideshow_id');_ It works. But I still have "A have B's primary key as a foreign key"